# Cannot get Alertdialog title, divider and buttons ID (Nullpointer exception)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I don't understand why I get a NPE..i'm using the same come on another class and it's working :

```
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
    alertdialog.setTitle("Title");
    alertdialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_gps);
    alertdialog.setMessage("Message");

    /*
    handling the buttons :
     */
    alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mcontext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog d = alertdialog.show();
    int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.very_light_gray));

    int textViewId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) d.findViewById(textViewId);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hot_orange));
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"));

    Button b = d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    b.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray2));
    b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.snow_primary));

    Button b2 = d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    b2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray2));
    b2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.snow_primary));
    d.show();
```

as you can see, I called `alerdialog.show()`before I tried to access to the buttons, divier etc..
the class where i have this function extends `activity`, i'm using the same code on another class that extends `DialogFragment`and it works..
thanks.

Comment: Where *exactly* is the nullpointer?

Comment: when i try to set the background color to the divider, or to the buttons.